Is there a way to prevent using functions on a queue object if the queue's memory was not initialized correctly?
When we create a Queue object a constructor is called and if the Queue is too large the memory allocation will fail and the constructor will throw a std::bad_alloc error.
Queue(const int capacity){
        try{
            arr = new int[capacity];
            front = 0, rear = 0;
            this->capacity = capacity;
        }
        catch(const std::bad_alloc& ba){
            cerr << "Failed to allocate memory for the queue!" << endl;
        }
    }

In runtime a user can call certain functions like enqueue() but the program will just say the Queue is full and won't do any harmful things. Is there any way for me to block the user from using functions on this Queue object after a failed memory allocation.
I tried to make a public function that just checks if the *arr is equal to nullptr and use it in the beginning of every single function in my Queue class but I find to be a bit of a hastle if I want to create new functions and too much function repitition for my Queue class.

Why would you catch an exception and leave the object in an unfinished state? Either handle the exception yourself by reinitializing to an  queue with a safe size, or let the exception propagate to the caller that passed in a bad capacity. After all, if I create a queue with capacity=1000000 sans error I fully expect to be able to stuff a million elements in there.

If exception is thrown during construction, I would guess any call to member functions is UB

Side note why are you still using new in c++ while there is std::vector<int>. Or in this case why don't you use one of the standard library queue types? Also if you need to write a queue of your own AND want/need to use new make sure you delete the copy constructors on Queue (and decide on what you want to do with the move constructors)

You're defeating the whole point of throwing exceptions. By catching the exception, you explicitly let the caller believe that the queue is usable, even when it is not.  Writing a message to cerr doesn't cut it, as the calling code will usually not monitor cerr and will happily proceed as if the queue is usable - and probably end up with some form of undefined behaviour.  The whole point of throwing an exception is so the caller cannot use your queue if allocation fails  -  the caller will only catch the exception if the caller can recover somehow.

@김선달 if the constructor throws, there is no object to call member function on.

.... and, if there is no object to call a member function on, any attempt to call a non-static member function for that non-existent object will cause undefined behaviour.

@Peter no, it'll be a syntax error

@Peter do you mean something like this https://godbolt.org/z/q54oGszon ?

@Caleth   I was thinking more on the lines of, since the OP is swallowing the exception in the constructor, Queue x(some_capacity);  x.some_operation();.     Since x is in an invalid/indeterminate state, the door is open for calling its non-static members to have undefined behaviour.

@Peter so you didnt actually mean "non-existant" but "in an invalid state" object

@463035818_is_not_an_ai   Change the i* to *ptr in the exception handler, and that would be (another way) along the lines of my thinking.

@Peter that's why we are advising against catching in the constructor. If you don't catch, there isn't an object in an invalid state

@Caleth I'm not arguing in favour of swallowing the exception.   My first comment stated that outright.

@Peter yes it was a typo :/ I wanted to show an example for your "non existant object -> causes ub". Though it was more than 1 typo, proper example would be this https://godbolt.org/z/GbaMnPP8d

@463035818_is_not_an_ai   That's more like it :-)

I was trying to make my own 'queue'  that is why I didn't use 'std::vector'. I don't have a copy constructor I just made the queue constructor in a stupid way. I just realised it while reading the comments. Thank you for the suggestions

@Peter I'd argue that this is the same issue as OP has now (even with int replaced by their Queue) just in a different look. The mistake is to catch but neither fix the cause nor retrhow. Actually I think once you do use exceptions the throwing part is mostly a nobrainer, but catching is not easy.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai  Catching needs to be done strategically - tactical uses such as calling a function or running a small code snippet and catching exceptions they produce don't work well (and simply swallowing exceptions without recovery is worse).   Practically, that often means "as little as possible"  (e.g. a small number of functions that ever catch exceptions) and the purpose of catching is recovery (so execution can continue), partial recovery (and then throw a possibly modified exception), or error reporting/logging (and then either rethrow or terminate the program).

If you catch in the constructor, you have made Queue worse to use. You should only catch an exception when you are able to handle it. That might be the immediate caller re-trying with a smaller capacity, or somewhere much further up the stack showing an error message on the UI.
E.g. if inserting into your queue can expand it, you have introduced the possibility of undefined behaviour in cases like this:
Queue queue(100); // caller assumes no allocations after this, because that's normal when providing a capacity
queue.push_back(1);
auto iter = queue.begin();
queue.push_back(2); // queue gets expanded, iter is invalidated
std::cout << *iter; // undefined behaviour

Instead if you let the exception propogate out of Queue::Queue, there is no queue object to call member functions on when allocation fails
try {
    Queue queue(100);
} catch (...) {}
queue.push_back(1); // error: queue not declared in this scope


Swallowing an exception in a container's constructor does not really change the potential for subsequent resizing to invalid iterators.   Calls of std::vector::push_back() also invalidate iterators, and its constructor does not swallow exceptions.

@Peter std::vector doesn't have a constructor that reserves, only one that resizes. Consider a class with a member std::vector that calls reserve in the constructor

I haven't realised that I had made it worse thank you for the advice. I will change the constructor so it works properly. Thank you again for the help
